# Query seems to be duplicated

Tags: php, categories, wp-query

I'm just hit a development brick wall and can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

I've running two WP_Query's the aim is one displays premium stockists and the other one displays the none premium stockists. I've added a  tick-box that allow's me to use a conditional to check if its a premium stockist or not.

1. How do I add the correct logic in *if the user is a premium member display the premium stockists. These must appear at the top of the page above the other stockists due to them been premium.
2. I'm using a plugin called Advanced custom fields to generate the premium true/false field. website is [enter link description here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/true-false/)

Code I've got.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'store-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array($_POST['region'])
            )
        )
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

$mapurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lj_mapurl', true); ?>

<div class="usercontent">
    <div class="stockist-content green-bg">
        <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="stockist-image">
        <?php   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $postthumnail_count++;
            the_post_thumbnail('stock');
        }
        ?> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div>
<a class="viewMap" href="<?php echo $mapurl; ?>" title="Find <?php the_title(); ?> on a map (opens in a new window)" target="_blank">View Map</a>
<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div>
<hr />
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, content not found</p>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'store-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array($_POST['region'])
            )
        )
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

$mapurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lj_mapurl', true); 
$premium = get_field('premium_stock_supplier');
if ( ! $premium ) { // this is basically short for $premium == false
    ?>

    <div class="usercontent">
        <div class="stockist-content">
            <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
            <?php the_content(); ?></div></div>


            <a class="viewMap" href="<?php echo $mapurl; ?>" title="Find <?php the_title(); ?> on a map (opens in a new window)" target="_blank">View Map</a>
            <div class="clr">&nbsp;</div>
            <hr />
            <?php  } ?>



        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, content not found</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

updated code for displaying premium stockists (doesn't work)

```
<?php
              $args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'premium',
            'meta_value' => '0',
            )
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'store-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array($_POST['region'])
            )
        )
    );
```

code for displaying none premium stockists (doesn't work)

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'premium',
            'meta_value' => '0',
            )
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'store-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array($_POST['region'])
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: How do  you identify premium users? Please pare that code down to only the part relevant to this question.

Comment: And can you indent correctly? The code is difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are showing the same output, because they are identical

Here is your first queries arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'store-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array($_POST['region'])
        )
    )
);
```

Here is your second queries arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'store-category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array($_POST['region'])
        )
    )
);
```

You ask for the same thing both times, you get the same thing both times.

Since you're using ACF you should query by the post meta for your ACF field:

e.g. something similar to this:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'premium', // I guessed your field would be called premium, but this might not be the case
    'meta_value' => 'yes'
);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

... etc..


$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'premium',
    'meta_value' => 'no'
);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

ACF fields are post meta/custom fields too, they're just wrapped behind a fancy UI/API

Comment: I'm aware of this Tom - maybe should of mentioned it - I'm looking to create a query that doesn't display the premium users.

Comment: And it posted before I could finish answering, see edited answer

Comment: Would the 'meta_value => 'no' be 'meta_value => 0' for false and '1' for true

Comment: probably, like the ACF field name/key I cant see what you've chosen as your premium and non premium values. Try grabbing the field and passing it into print_r or var_dump to see what the respective values are to put in your query